# rotate complex eigenvector

Tags: complex-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, rotations

I'm computing the eigenvectors of a real non-symmetric Matrix. I know that complex eigenvectors would come in conjugate. 
However, does anybody know a algorithm to **rotate such complex eigenvectors** that

- i) its real and imaginary parts are orthogonal
- ii) real part has norm 1 while imaginary parts has norm greater than 1.

The context is calculation of Empirical Normal Mode.

Say, I have a system evolve as $\frac{\mathrm{d}X}{\mathrm{d}t}=LX+\text{gaussian noise}$, $X$ is vector and $L$ is matrix.

Then the eigenvector of $L$ gives the "Empirical Normal Mode" and exponential of eigenvalues are corresponding timescale of each mode.
In general, $X$ could be represented as linear combinations of Normal Modes. But $X$ is real then complex eigenvectors should appear in conjugate pair. I want to combine each complex conjugate pair in a unique way, that is, satisfy above two conditions.

Thanks!

Comment: Some more context would be nice. Why do you need such an algorithm?

Comment: That said I don't think what you're asking is possible. In general if you have an eigenvalue equation $Ax=\lambda x$, $x\neq0$ an eigenvector of $A$, then a general transformation of $x$ to another vector, say $y$ will mean that $y$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.

Comment: Eigenvectors are preserved under scalar multiplication and if the underlying scalar field of the vector space you're working on is $\mathbb{C}$ then multiplication by $e^{i\theta}$ will rotate your vector by $\theta$ in complex coordinate space but this operation acts on the real and imaginary parts similarly so you can't use this to fulfil your two conditions

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've added more info.